# Save Macro-enabled workbook as "filename" + Current Date using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find out if it is possible to write VBA to save a file that I have open as "filename" (in this case "PO_Cancellation_Issues - ") + the current date? So for today it would save as "PO_Cancellation_Issues - 02192018".  I would be open to any date format that saves mmddyyyy.

Thanks.

Comment: `Format(Date,"mmddyyyy")`

Comment: Yes. It is possible. I suggest you invest some of your time to google for code you will readily find on the Internet. Once you have that code you can come back here if you need help customising it to your particular needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub foo()
'FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
'FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
'FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
'FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
'FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4158
'FileExtStr = ".prn": FileFormatNum = 36

FileFormatNum = 51
TempFilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
Filename = "PO_Cancellation_Issues - "
TempFileName = Filename & " " & Format(Now, "mmddyyyy")

    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```